# Почему блок div класса article вылетает из потока?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Использую систему сеток `960gs`. Вопрос: почему блок `div` с классом `article` вылетает из потока если к нему не применить свойство `clear`? Так же добавляет странности то, что блок, находящийся в коде HTML выше него так же имеет класс `grid_...` и `push_...`. НО! Он почему-то отображается нормально и без применения свойства `clear`!!! Почему так?

```css
/*Мой CSS*/

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

#header {
  background-color: rgb(63, 65, 67);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

#header li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-style: italic;
}

#header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
}

div.article {
  text-align: left;
  clear: left;
}


/*960GS*/

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.push_1,
.pull_1,
.push_2,
.pull_2,
.push_3,
.pull_3,
.push_4,
.pull_4,
.push_5,
.pull_5,
.push_6,
.pull_6,
.push_7,
.pull_7,
.push_8,
.pull_8,
.push_9,
.pull_9,
.push_10,
.pull_10,
.push_11,
.pull_11 {
  position: relative;
}

.container_12 .grid_1 {
  width: 60px;
}

.container_12 .grid_2 {
  width: 140px;
}

.container_12 .grid_3 {
  width: 220px;
}

.container_12 .grid_4 {
  width: 300px;
}

.container_12 .grid_5 {
  width: 380px;
}

.container_12 .grid_6 {
  width: 460px;
}

.container_12 .grid_7 {
  width: 540px;
}

.container_12 .grid_8 {
  width: 620px;
}

.container_12 .grid_9 {
  width: 700px;
}

.container_12 .grid_10 {
  width: 780px;
}

.container_12 .grid_11 {
  width: 860px;
}

.container_12 .grid_12 {
  width: 940px;
}

.container_12 .push_1 {
  left: 80px;
}

.container_12 .push_2 {
  left: 160px;
}

.container_12 .push_3 {
  left: 240px;
}

.container_12 .push_4 {
  left: 320px;
}

.container_12 .push_5 {
  left: 400px;
}

.container_12 .push_6 {
  left: 480px;
}

.container_12 .push_7 {
  left: 560px;
}

.container_12 .push_8 {
  left: 640px;
}

.container_12 .push_9 {
  left: 720px;
}

.container_12 .push_10 {
  left: 800px;
}

.container_12 .push_11 {
  left: 880px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_12">
  <div id="header">
    <div class="grid_5">
      ЛОГОТИП
    </div>
    <div class="grid_7">
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Главная /</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Новости /</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Архивы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">О нас /</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="grid_6 push_6">
      <h1 style="color:#b5c1ad">Что такое VELOHELD?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 push_9 article">
      <h4 style="color:#b5c1ad">21 февраля 2019</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте рабочий пример, который можно запустить

Comment: @E_K почему нельзя запустить этот пример? Он рабочий

Comment: я хочу запустить его здесь, а не копировать ваш код, искать и качать сетку.

Comment: @E_K теперь добавил. Можете запускать

Comment: Зачем вы столько ресурсов тратите на `float`, если его в 99% случаев не используют?

Answer (score 0):

Без `clear` блок `.article` позиционируется за  блоком `grid_6 push_6`,как и должны `float` элементы, а не выпадает из потока. Но, вы смещаете эти блоки относительно их реального местоположения с помощью `push` класса, поэтому они выглядят не так как блоки выше.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите чтобы див был с новой строки, то используйте размер сетки такой же как у контейнера, в данном случае у Вас `container_12` значит и для дива внтури ставьте `grid_12`. Либо же между дивами вставить пусто с классом clear (`<div class="clear"></div>`) В коде показал два примера, оба дают одинаковый результат:

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
#header {
    background-color: rgb(63, 65, 67);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
#header li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 3px;
    font-style: italic; 
}
#header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.nav {

    float: right;
}
div.article {
    text-align: left;
    /*clear: left;*/
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="styles/КРУТИ ПЕДАЛИ.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/960gs/0/960.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container_12">
   <div id="header">
    <div class="grid_5">
     ЛОГОТИП
    </div>
    <div class="grid_7">
     <div class="nav">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Главная /</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Новости /</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Архивы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">О нас /</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="wrapper">
   <!--Вариант 1 -->
     <div class="grid_6 push_6">
      <h1 style="color:#b5c1ad">Что такое  VELOHELD?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="grid_3 push_9 article">
      <h4 style="color:#b5c1ad">21 февраля 2019</h4>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <!--Вариант 2 -->
     <div class="grid_12 push_6">
      <h1 style="color:#b5c1ad">Что такое  VELOHELD?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_12 push_9 article">
      <h4 style="color:#b5c1ad">21 февраля 2019</h4>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 2-ой вариант не работает. И я не это спрашивал. Мой вопрос:  почему блок div с классом article вылетает из потока если к нему не применить свойство clear? Так же добавляет странности то, что блок, находящийся в коде HTML выше него так же имеет класс grid_... и push_... НО! Он почему-то отображается нормально и без применения свойства clear!!! Почему так?